# scale image for fit size without stretch

Tags: c#

I want resize an `Image` for fit a size (width and height) without stretch the original image.

[image]

My code, resize the image to the specified size but stretch the original image.

[image]

this is the code:

```
public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height)
{
    var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

    destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
    {
        graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

        using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
        {
            wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.Tile);
            graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
        }
    }

    return destImage;
}
```

Comment: The answer is in your title: you need to *scale*, not resize, the image: Reduce/Increase the H or W by a percent so it fits the new size

Comment: @Plutonix ok, but i'm here because i don't know how do it!

Comment: I get that.  For the first, horiz one, you need to increase the size so the width matches the target width.  You want to size up from 276 to about 340 or 123%.  That will leave a lot of extra vertical image which gets cropped.  For the other, scale based on the vertical

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to **Scale with respect to Aspect Ratio**.

What we should do is to get a factor and resize both width and height by that factor.
And we need not to go above desired width and height (that's why we use `Math.Min` on both width and height ratios).

```
double oldWidth = image.Width;
double oldHeight = image.Height;

var widthRatio = width / oldWidth;
var heightRatio = height / oldHeight;

var factor = Math.Min(widthRatio, heightRatio);
```

and here we use it like this:

```
var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)(factor * oldWidth), (int)(factor * oldHeight));
```